# How can I install github3.py via my setup.py?

Tags: python, setup.py, github3.py

I want to use github3.py module on my pyramid application.

In my develop enviroment, I can install github3.py via pip and this works fine.
But I need to add github3.py to setup.py for production enviroment  because I want to setup production enviroment by one single command. `python setup.py install`

So I wrote setup.py for my pyramid application like below.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

requires = [
    # add only this module to confirm the problem.
    'github3.py'
    ]

setup(
      ...
      install_requires=requires,
      ...
      )
```

When I execute install command, I got error.

```
$ python setup.py install

...
error: The 'uritemplate.py>=0.2.0' distribution was not found and is required by github3.py
```

I executed install command on new virtualenv to make sure enviroment is clean.

How can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

ADD: the complete output is here. I use `develep` parameter instead of `install` to get the complete output here. Because the output is too long when I use `install` parameter. I want to install github3.py in my new development enviroment also.

```
$ python setup.py develop                                                            
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'message_extractors'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running develop
running egg_info
writing requirements to saleaddirect.egg-info/requires.txt
writing saleaddirect.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to saleaddirect.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to saleaddirect.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to saleaddirect.egg-info/entry_points.txt
reading manifest file 'saleaddirect.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching '*.rst'
warning: no files found matching '*.mak' under directory 'saleaddirect'
warning: no files found matching '*.mako' under directory 'saleaddirect'
warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'saleaddirect'
warning: no files found matching '*.xml' under directory 'saleaddirect'
writing manifest file 'saleaddirect.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
Creating /home/yazaki/.virtualenvs/test-pyramid/lib/python2.7/site-packages/saleaddirect.egg-link (link to .)
Adding saleaddirect 0.1 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/yazaki/work/exsoft.saleaddirect/saleaddirect
Processing dependencies for saleaddirect==0.1
Searching for github3.py
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/github3.py/
Best match: github3.py 1.0.0a4
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/e5/8d/b97e44ca548ceb17c33aa8e4c5cc884fa0a11bd88247690c9915fd73ecc4/github3.py-1.0.0a4.tar.gz#md5=a8513584fd3b11746b14e91e00a74960
Processing github3.py-1.0.0a4.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-LKvb9U/github3.py-1.0.0a4/setup.cfg
Running github3.py-1.0.0a4/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-LKvb9U/github3.py-1.0.0a4/egg-dist-tmp-IfRPcR
no previously-included directories found matching '*.pyc'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Moving github3.py-1.0.0a4-py2.7.egg to /home/yazaki/.virtualenvs/test-pyramid/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Adding github3.py 1.0.0a4 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/yazaki/.virtualenvs/test-pyramid/lib/python2.7/site-packages/github3.py-1.0.0a4-py2.7.egg
Searching for uritemplate.py>=0.2.0
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/uritemplate.py/
Best match: uritemplate.py 3.0.2
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/12/97/e12695c7d7710143767022ce931061b4a6b5b19982b20ecf5d71cdde3da1/uritemplate.py-3.0.2.tar.gz#md5=ee63cccbba43851e18f902f86cba0688
Processing uritemplate.py-3.0.2.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-eCXkH9/uritemplate.py-3.0.2/setup.cfg
Running uritemplate.py-3.0.2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-eCXkH9/uritemplate.py-3.0.2/egg-dist-tmp-ToLyxT
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[cdo]' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Moving uritemplate-2.0.0-py2.7.egg to /home/yazaki/.virtualenvs/test-pyramid/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Adding uritemplate 2.0.0 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /home/yazaki/.virtualenvs/test-pyramid/lib/python2.7/site-packages/uritemplate-2.0.0-py2.7.egg
error: The 'uritemplate.py>=0.2.0' distribution was not found and is required by github3.py
```

Comment: Could you provide the complete output? There absolutely are satisfactory versions of `uritemplate.py` on PyPI.

Comment: Thanks @sigmavirus24. I added the complete output.

Comment: I'm thoroughly confused @yazaki, it's finding, downloading, and installing `uritemplate.py` for you and yet it prints that it cannot find it. What version of setuptools are you using?

Comment: I'm confused too. My setuptools version is 18.2. 
I setup cloud9 test enviroment ( https://ide.c9.io/yazaki/test-python ). So if you have cloud9 account, you can see the same error when you execute `python setup.py install` on console of clound9.

Comment: Can you upgrade the version of setuptools used? That version is over a year old I think.

Comment: I appreciate your continuous help. I built other new clean environment on docker `docker run --rm -it python:2.7 /bin/bash`. The version of setuptools on the environment is 26.0.0. But unfortunately the result is same.

Comment: FWIW, I'm getting the same issue on circle ci for a project that uses requests. I'll report back if/when i get to the bottom of it.

Comment: For me this only fails on python 2.7.10. I haven't figured out why, but upgrading to 2.7.11 solved it (2.7.12 isn't available on circleci)